# How to get the cursors's relative coordinate?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a canvas. And I need to get the cursor's coordinate relative to the left-top corner of the canvas when the left button is pressed. But all that Javascript gives me is `clientX`, `clientY`, `screenX` and `screenY`. I was trying to calculate this. But no `clientX`, `clientY`, `screenX` or `screenY` is available for the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your canvas

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

You can first get the position of the Canvas using

```
var element = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
```

That'll give you an object with properties: top, right, bottom and left. So to calculate the cursor's coordinates relative to the left-top corner, you just subtract that from your the top-left X and Y coordinates from clientX and clientY.

```
var canvasCursor = { top: clientY - rect.top,
                    left: clientX - rect.left }
```